# Combine multiple GET requests using cURL into a single page

Tags: php, css, curl

I'm a cURL newbie. I'm simulating a conversation that my browser has with a specific server. The browser makes several GET requests for a page, some CSS files and some image files too.

I want to print out my result as a browsable web page. How can I combine all these files into one page? Also, how can I make the links on the page show as absolute URLS instead of all linking to my webserver?

```
# Create the PHP/CURL session
$ch = curl_init();

# Define target page
$target = ADDR;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target); // Define target site
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Return page in string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt"); // Tell PHP/CURL where to write cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt"); // Tell PHP/CURL which cookies to send
$page = curl_exec($ch);

$tmp = return_between($page, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"","\" />", EXCL );
$token = urlencode($tmp);
$tmp = return_between($page, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"","\" />", EXCL );
$token1 = urlencode($tmp);

# Define the login form data
$target = ADDR;
$form_data="__VIEWSTATE=".$token1."&__EVENTVALIDATION=".$token."&SearchType=rbSearchTypeBirth&txtSurname=".$surname."&txtGivenNames=".$givenname."&txtFromYear=".$datefrom."&txtToYear=".$dateto."&txtSpouseSurname=&txtSpouseGivenNames=&txtFather=&txtMother=&dropdownlistGender=M&txtLocation=&DummyForEnterSubmit=&btnSubmit=Search&hidPageNumber=1&hidPageTotal=1";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, ADDR);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_array);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $form_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt"); // Tell PHP/CURL where to write cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt"); // Tell PHP/CURL which cookies to send
$page = curl_exec($ch);

echo $page;
```

Comment: So far, I am able to display a page whose links all point to my server and which has no images and CSS.

Comment: I have thought of using DOMDocument, but I don't believe its possible to send GET requests using DOM

Comment: Post some code, we can't guess here.

Comment: Maybe something like this: $page=str_replace('src="/', 'src="'.$target.'/',$page);

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading up on how to use Xpath to make this simpler